# Columns in join table are NOT NULL

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class:

```
class Author {
    String name
    static hasMany = [superFantasticAndAwesomeBooks: Book, superBadAndUltraBoringBooks: Book]
}
```

This is all nice when using the in-memory database, however, when running on Oracle the `Book` collections are modeled in a join table which cannot be created because the column names are too long.

So, then I tried specifying the join table properties:

```
static mapping = {
    superFantasticAndAwesomeBooks joinTable: [key: awesomeBooks]
    superBadAndUltraBoringBooks joinTable: [key: boringBooks]
}
```

The problem (which doesn't happen if `joinTable` isn't specified) is that the join table is created where columns correspoinding to `awesomeBooks` and `boringBooks` are `NOT NULL` (they need to be nullable because a `Book` will be an `awesomeBook` or a `boringBook`)

Is there any way to configure `joinTable` to allow `NULL` columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up using 2 join tables:

```
static mapping = {
    superFantasticAndAwesomeBooks joinTable: [name: 'awesomeBooks', key: 'book_id']
    superBadAndUltraBoringBooks joinTable: [name: 'boringBooks', key: 'book_id']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to map the join table yourself with a Domain class, for example:

```
class AuthorBook {
    Author author
    Book book
    String status

    static constraints = {
        author(nullable:false)
        book(nullable:false)
        status(nullable:false,inList:['SuperFantasticAndAwesome','SuperBadAndUltraBoring'])
    }
}
```

So your Author class becomes:

```
class Author {
    ...
    static hasMany = [authorBooks:AuthorBook]
}
```

In this way the status is stored as a value of the join and statuses can be added, updated, or removed as needed in the future.  It does have the side effect of having to query through the AuthorBook class to get to the associated Books.

See also: http://grails.org/Many-to-Many+Mapping+without+Hibernate+XML